# ionic service init before loading controller

Tags: ionic-framework

I have service which has asynchronous init of parameter and I want that every controller to wait until the init will be finished.

The problem is that the getObject method is being called by the controller before the init of parameters variable is finished.

The service:

```
angular.module('core')
.factory('localstorage', ['$window', '$cordovaSQLite', '$q',
function ($window, $cordovaSQLite, $q) {
  var db;
  var parameters = {};
  if (window.cordova) {
    db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({name: "my.db"}); //device
  } else {
    db = window.openDatabase("my.db", '1', 'life', 1024 * 1024 * 100);
  }

  var promise = $q(function (resolve, reject) {
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "SELECT * FROM life_table")
      .then(function (res) {
        if (res.rows.length == 0) {
          $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS life_table (key text primary key, value text)");
        }
        else {
          for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; ++i) {
            parameters[res.rows[i].key] = JSON.parse(res.rows[i].value);
          }
        }
        resolve(parameters);
      });
  });

  return {
    promise: promise,
    getObject: function (key) {
      var query = "SELECT value FROM life_table where key = ?";
      $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [key]).then(function (res) {
        if (res.rows.length > 0) {
          console.log("getObject: " + res.rows[0].value);
        }
      }, function (err) {
        console.error(err);
      });
      return parameters[key];
    }
  }
}]);
```

the config:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
 $stateProvider

  .state('navigator', {
    url: '/',
    abstract: true,
    controller: 'NavigatorCtrl',
    resolve: {
      'MyServiceData': function (localstorage) {
        // localstorage will also be injectable in the controller
        return localstorage.promise;
      }
    }
  })

  .state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'loginCtrl',
    resolve: {
      'MyServiceData': function (localstorage) {
        // localstorage will also be injectable in the controller
        return localstorage.promise;
      }
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Shalom Dor!

**Option 1**

Make a chain of promises and return the factory only after all promises are resolved. This will prevent the controller from running as the factory dependency will not be returned until the desired promises are resolved.

**Option 2**

Create some sort initialization function in your service that returns a promise (you can use $q). Execute it inside `$ionicPlaform.ready()` and only run the controller logic after you got the promise.

In the controller:

```
MyService.initialize().then(function () {
    // Service initialized, do stuff...
});
```

In the service:

```
returned.initialize = function () {
    var d = q.defer();
    // Do stuff...
    // Resolve 'd' when you finished initializing the service using 'd.resolve()'.
    return d.promise;
};
```